# How to assert new data dynamically in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have previously define a few facts dynamically as below.

```
% declare dynamic facts
:- dynamic title/2.
:- dynamic author/2.
:- dynamic publisher/2.
:- dynamic price/2.
:- dynamic call_number/2.
:- dynamic edition/2.
:- dynamic data_disk/2.
```

and assert these facts every time the program runs

```
:- assert(title(book1, 'Elementary Statistics')).
:- assert(title(book2, 'Statistics for Engineers')).
:- assert(title(book3, 'Statistics for Engineers and Scientists')).
:- assert(title(book4, 'IT in Language Learning')).

:- assert(author(book1, 'Patricia Wilson')).
:- assert(author(book2, 'James Mori')).
:- assert(author(book3, 'James Mori')).
:- assert(author(book4, 'O Ivan')).

:- assert(publisher(book1, 'Addison Wesley')).
:- assert(publisher(book2, 'World Scientific')).
:- assert(publisher(book3, 'World Scientific')).
:- assert(publisher(book4, 'Universal Press')).

:- assert(price(book1, 75)).
:- assert(price(book2, 125)).
:- assert(price(book3, 125)).
:- assert(price(book4, 5)).

:- assert(call_number(book1, 'QA373')).
:- assert(call_number(book2, 'QA673')).
:- assert(call_number(book3, 'QA674')).
:- assert(call_number(book4, 'QA007')).

:- assert(edition(book1, 1)).
:- assert(edition(book2, 3)).
:- assert(edition(book3, 2)).
:- assert(edition(book4, 1)).

:- assert(data_disk(book1, 'No')).
:- assert(data_disk(book2, 'Yes')).
:- assert(data_disk(book3, 'Yes')).
:- assert(data_disk(book4, 'No')).
```

As you can see the facts are in a certain order

```
book1
book2
book3
book4
```

How can I get the last X, where X is bookX, and increment by 1 so that the new book to be inserted will always be (X+1)?

Answer (score 1):

You found one solution (i.e., count the existing facts, and add 1), which works but has one major drawback: It makes the run time of adding a single new fact **proportional to the number of already asserted facts**. This means that asserting a series of `N` facts takes time proportional to `N`<sup>**2**</sup>.

Ideally, we would like to have a situation where asserting a single fact is in 𝒪(1), and asserting *N* facts is thus in 𝒪(*N*).

One way to achieve this is to reconsider your initial representation of books.

For example, suppose that you present your books like this (some data omitted for brevity):

```
book([title('Elementary Statistics'),
      author('Patricia Wilson'),
      price(75)]).
book([title('Statistics for Engineers'),
      author('James Mori'),
      publisher('World Scientific')]).
```

Note that this representation allows us to omit fields that are only present in some of the books. Other representations would also make sense.

We can easily fetch all these facts with `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(Book, book(Book), Books).
```

That's **linear** in the number of such facts.

Further, let us define `assert_book_/3` as follows:

```
assert_book_(Book, N0, N) :-
        memberchk(title(Title), Book),
        memberchk(author(Author), Book),
        assertz(title(N0,Title)),
        assertz(author(N0,Author)),
        N #= N0 + 1.
```

For the sake of example, I am focusing on the **title** and **author**. I leave extending this as an exercise.

The arguments of this predicate are:

- the **book** to be asserted, represented as a list of attributes
- the **current index** `N0`
- the **next index** `N1`, which is simply *one greater* than `N0`.

Now the main point: These arguments are in a suitable order to **fold** the predicate over a **list of books**, using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `foldl/4`:

```
?- findall(Book, book(Book), Books),
   foldl(assert_book_, Books, 1, _).
```

After running this query, we have:

```
?- title(N, T).
N = 1,
T = 'Elementary Statistics' ;
N = 2,
T = 'Statistics for Engineers'.
```

And similar facts for `author/2` in the database:

```
?- author(N, T).
N = 1,
T = 'Patricia Wilson' ;
N = 2,
T = 'James Mori'.
```

Thus, we have used `foldl/4` to **implicitly** keep track of the running index we need, and achieved a solution that has the desired running time.

---

Note that there is also a wise-cracking solution for your task:

```
assert_title(Book, Title) :-
        atom_concat(book, N0, Book),
        atom_number(N0, N),
        assertz(title(N, Title)).
```

This is obviously not what you looking for, but would work for the example you show, if you use for example:

```
:- assert_title(book1, 'Elementary Statistics').
:- assert_title(book2, 'Statistics for Engineers').
```

Now we have again:

```
?- title(N, Title).
N = 1,
Title = 'Elementary Statistics' ;
N = 2,
Title = 'Statistics for Engineers'.
```

The joke here is that you have actually entered the running index already, and we can use `atom_concat/3` to obtain it:

```
?- atom_concat(book, N0, book1),
   atom_number(N0, N).
N0 = '1',
N = 1.
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my mind at the nearest Starbucks and came up with the simplest answer.

```
add_book :-
  aggregate_all(count, title(_,_), Count),
  NewCount is Count + 1,
  atom_concat('book', NewCount, NewBook).
```

The aggregate_all function will count number of title predicates that's available in my knowledge base and some calculation will be performed.

I am open to better suggestion though, do reply if you have a better approach.